# How to inject a const char* in to the FILE class

Tags: c++

How can I modify this function to read from a string instead of a file? glfxin is obviously a FILE object. If I could somehow inject a const char* in to the FILE class, I would be set. Any ideas?

```
bool glfxParseEffectFromFile( int effect, const char* file )
{
    bool retVal=true;

    fopen_s(&glfxin, file, "r");
    if(glfxin==NULL) {
        gEffects[effect]->Log()<<"Cannot open file "<<file<<endl;
        gEffects[effect]->Active()=false;
        return false;
    }
    try {
        //glfxdebug=1;
        gEffect=gEffects[effect];

        string fname(file);
        size_t lastSlash=fname.find_last_of('/')+1;
        size_t lastBackSlash=fname.find_last_of('\\')+1;
        lastSlash=max(lastSlash, lastBackSlash);
        gEffect->Dir()=fname.substr(0, lastSlash);

        glfxrestart(glfxin);
        glfxset_lineno(1);
        glfxparse();
    }
    catch(const char* err) {
        gEffect->Log()<<err<<endl;
        gEffect->Active()=false;
        retVal=false;
    }
    catch(const string& err) {
        gEffect->Log()<<err<<endl;
        gEffect->Active()=false;
        retVal=false;
    }
    catch(...) {
        gEffect->Log()<<"Unknown error occurred during parsing of "<<file<<endl;
        gEffect->Active()=false;
        retVal=false;
    }

    fclose(glfxin);
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: How do you want to "inject a `const char *` into the FILE class"? Do you mean `fmemopen()`?

Comment: That would be perfect actually! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On POSIX-compliant sytems, you can use the [`fmemopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) function to open a character array as a `FILE *` object.